# Python: Sum over second row of 3 dimensional list

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum

I´m more or less new to python and trying to build an optimization model with gurobi.

My problem ist that i have a list of variables `a[i][t][s]` and need to sum the up for one of my constraints.

For the other constraints i have used the function `np.sum(a[i][t])` which gave me the the sum `a[i][t][0] + a[i][t][1] + ... + a[i][t][s]` which was exactly what i needed.

For the next constraints i need a function that gives me `a[i][1][s] + a[i][2][s] + ... + a[i][t][s]` and have no idea how to get it and didn´t find anything online about it either.

I hope someone can help me to find the code to fix the first and the third value instead of the first and the second.

thanks alot but if i sum over the axis i get more than one expression.
The result looks like:

```
> <gurobi.LinExpr: a[0, 0, 0] + a[0, 1, 0] + a[0, 2, 0] + ... 
> <gurobi.LinExpr: a[0, 0, 1] + a[0, 1, 1] + a[0, 2, 1] + ...
```

and so on. But the thing i need is just one expression where i and s are fixed and the sum goes over all the different t values. I now used

```
for i in dataid:
        for t in possible_demand.index:
            m.addConstr(np.sum([row[t] for row in a[i]]) == 1)
    m.update()
```

Comment: np.sum has a second argument, which is the axis along which you want to sum => the first sum you created was most likely, np.sum(a, 2) and the one you want should be np.sum(a, 1)

Comment: can you add the results of your tests to your question? I don't know what you got and what you expected

Comment: i edited the question and hope you understand what i mean. With the new code it worked (but im sure its not perfect :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexing to select the columns then use `sum` :

```
np.sum(a[i,::,s])
```

Demo:

```
>>> z
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 1]]])
>>> z[0,::,0]
array([1, 4])
>>> np.sum(z[0,::,0])
5
>>> z[1,::,0]
array([0, 3])
>>> z[2,::,2]
array([6, 1])
```

If you want to get the columns of a list you can use `zip` :

```
>>> a=list(z)
>>> cl=[zip(*i) for i in a]
[[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (0, 3)], [(4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)]]
>>> sum(cl[0][0]) #= z[0,::,0]
5
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i hoped to do this with a list and not an array. I was looking for somethink that makes the variable a column in the middle like a[i][???][s]

Comment: @Niko glad of that! you can tell this to community by accepting and voting the answer!

Comment: Sadly i can only accept and not vote cause i need 15 reputation to vote

Answer (score 0):

Use a slice:

```
>>> A=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> A[:,1]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> np.sum(A[:,1])
12
```

For multidimensions, you use [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
>>> B=np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> B
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Suppose you want the data from col 2 of all three arrays:

```
>>> C=B[...,2]
>>> C
array([[ 2,  5,  8],
       [11, 14, 17],
       [20, 23, 26]])
```

Which you can also use in `sum`:

```
>>> np.sum(B[...,2])
126
```

You say *hoped there is a way to do this with a list and don´t change the list to an array.*

The result of a slice in numpy is **not** necessarily a new list; it is most likely a [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view). This is easily demonstrated:

```
>>> B
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
>>> C=B[...,2]
>>> C
array([[ 2,  5,  8],
       [11, 14, 17],
       [20, 23, 26]])
>>> B[0,0,2]=555
>>> B
array([[[  0,   1, 555],
        [  3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8]],

       [[  9,  10,  11],
        [ 12,  13,  14],
        [ 15,  16,  17]],

       [[ 18,  19,  20],
        [ 21,  22,  23],
        [ 24,  25,  26]]])
>>> C
array([[555,   5,   8],
       [ 11,  14,  17],
       [ 20,  23,  26]])
```

You can see that the view `C` changes in real time as the underlying array `B` is changed.

You can also test if something is a view:

```
>>> C.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False              # if it were a new array, this would be True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

So the most *efficient* method with a numpy array is to use numpy tools. If you translate into Python data, in most cases, it will be slower and use more memory.

Comment: Thank you very much but hoped there is a way to do this with a list and don´t change the list to an array.